# How to check if App has brought new update in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, google-play, google-play-console

When I update the application on google play in the application that I have published with flutter and connected with API ends, I want the user to be notified when the application is opened.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [new_version](https://pub.dev/packages/new_version) package. it will update the user with dialog box with your custom message

here is the sample code make sure **androidId:"put your app id here"** is correct,

```
final newVersion = NewVersion(androidId:"put your app id here");
    final status = await newVersion.getVersionStatus();
    if (status != null) {
  print('Store version (${status.storeVersion}) and local Version(${status.localVersion}) ');

  if (status.storeVersion != status.localVersion)
     newVersion.showUpdateDialog(
        context: context,
        versionStatus: status,
        dialogTitle: 'Your Custom Title',
        dialogText: 'your Custom Text',
      );
```

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1 . I couldn't solve this error

Comment: Check whether appId is correct?

Comment: @ Memiş Ali Tufan i edited the answer check now

Comment: The data list in the package seems empty for me.

Comment: what's the output you are getting from print statement?

Comment: empty set  "[ ]"

Comment: check your app id is that correct?

Comment: I solved it by breaking the new version package thanks